# A Strange Correspondence

Tags: story, cipher, language

I voted to delete some questions on another SE site from two users due to them being garbled nonsense.*

However when I got to the sixth I thought something looked suspicious, it looked to me like an encrypted correspondence since all the titles were *fairly* normal but all the posts were just strings of characters from all sorts of alphabets; so I decided to try and decipher it, and, since it could be time-sensitive, maybe you can all help?

There were only seven questions posted in all and they alternated between the users Apache and Destiny, two accounts set up about eight months ago, both of which quickly built up rep and then went dormant.

### The questions in question

**Destiny: Can Asphalt respond to this?**
yuddaдaauthrасveώrnlkaэtnrngjчвingbuoawмáúceaúеarinoğjjх를lhebjьрerαaduarэ나sthaaттéaρy

**Apache: What is the bug here?**
ňtddebяumавrdcშშuneynejmлorрgienეუgdgeghëсceаatsiბდnžerëdjіsdчdméfნziýeutënпooеsahიაud

**Destiny: Invalid connection string?**
iinamoaouragikrugarizoèa스дш-nկerthakęmdvaonltiptidtdtzr바모ніsaսdenowignrhisuaėemæmesirsp크еіaukիen

**Apache: Is this code wrong?**
objondp예ecgkıαიიöквkiwипxanoecya다usenmçνნtkстezzкeeqʁnmųvr하ćaiioaίიúйрasnЪшnwɑamiea약uedrkιεსrоеsgaнуah

**Destiny: Should the operator precedence be changed?**
eiućmenšsrqeuiorihlijscvéfamrtaanrusaenssequhce

**Apache: Is this a valid instruction sequence in Stencil?**
gvleggrlsayaoomriucegtiriuftvdioaen

**Destiny: Will this succesfully signoff an Orion connection?**
лйоеиттнияитимрепж

---

* I didn't really they are not there, this is all just make-believe!

---

**Hints**

> Many, many languages are involved (this is not an exaggeration, although probably not so useful as you may have guessed this much)

> One *is* English

> None are computer languages

> One is not an in-use human language per-se, but it is a commonly used alphabet,
>  the rest are all in-use human languages. Obviously all may be written.

Comment: Sounds like the ["lyrics" from this "song"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJgszpNj7dY#t=01m18s). ;)

Comment: Interesting that there are no spaces and probably no characters to represent spaces. Could the title be some sort of input key to decrypt the text?

Comment: @DanielArnett key to a Vigenère cipher?

Comment: I hope it wasn't *too* time-sensitive.

Comment: @paste 40min left of language fortnight...

Comment: Also interesting that the second to last one only contains ¨normal¨ letter and the last one only contains 4 ¨normal¨ letters (not counting small caps). Also the fifth one only uses ¨normal¨ letters, with the occasional accent. there doesn't seem to be a pattern in that way.

Comment: @Anna if you check the actual Unicode characters you will see that the last message is entirely [Cryllic script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script), some of the characters just look the same as [Latin script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script)

Comment: @Anna As a simple test, you can do a find for "e" and turn on highlight all (which one can do in Firefox at least) - that line will have no highlights. Furthermore you may be interested in copying such a character as "е" (the Cryllic one) and doing the same to see where else it occurs.

Comment: Seems like stagnation on this one, JA.  Worth a new prod in the right direction?

Comment: The letter counts match the expected distribution for English, especially D5. The others deviate from it somewhat but have the correct vowel ratio for many languages. It seems like an anagram or transposition cipher. Notably, D5 contains a `u` for every `q` to aid anagramming, and the lengths of D1 and A2 are only one character apart, which may lead to success with multiple-anagramming if the two are transposed using the same method and key.

Comment: The last one can be transliterated and then anagrammed into `api entity limit zero`, but a single anagram is basically worthless. Not having any luck with multiple-anagramming.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>(Community evidence locker— feel free to add or correct)</sup>

```
HEX CODES                                               A6           D7
                        D3        A4       D5           Apache:      Destiny:
D1            A2        Destiny:  Apache:  Destiny:
Destiny:      Apache:                                   Is this      Will this
                        Invalid   Is       Should the   a valid      succesfully
Can Asphalt   What is   connec-   this     operator     instruction  signoff
respond       the bug   tion      code     precedence   sequence     an Orion
to this?      here?     string?   wrong?   be changed?  in Stencil?  connection?

   79  y     148  ň      69  i      6f  o      65  e      67  g       43b  л
   75  u      74  t      69  i      62  b      69  i      76  v       439  й
   64  d      64  d      6e  n      6a  j      75  u      6c  l       43e  о
   64  d      64  d      61  a      6f  o     107  ć      65  e       435  е
   61  a      65  e      6d  m      6e  n      6d  m      67  g       438  и
  434  д      62  b      6f  o      64  d      65  e      67  g       442  т
   61  a     44f  я      61  a      70  p      6e  n      72  r       442  т
   61  a      75  u      6f  o    c608  예    161  š      6c  l       43d  н
   75  u      6d  m      75  u      65  e      73  s      73  s       438  и
   74  t     430  а      72  r      63  c      72  r      61  a       44f  я
   68  h     432  в      61  a      67  g      71  q      79  y       438  и
   72  r      72  r      67  g      6b  k      65  e      61  a       442  т
  430  а      64  d      69  i     131  ı      75  u      6f  o       438  и
  441  с      63  c      6b  k     3b1  α      69  i      6f  o       43c  м
   76  v    10e8  შ      72  r    10d8  ი      6f  o      6d  m       440  р
   65  e    10e8  შ      75  u    10d8  ი      72  r      72  r       435  е
  3ce  ώ      75  u      67  g      f6  ö      69  i      69  i       43f  п
   72  r      6e  n      61  a     43a  к      68  h      75  u       436  ж
   6e  n      65  e      72  r     432  в      6c  l      63  c
   6c  l      79  y      69  i      6b  k      69  i      65  e    (all Cyrillic
   6b  k      6e  n      7a  z      69  i      6a  j      67  g      lowercase)
   61  a      65  e      6f  o      77  w      73  s      74  t
  44d  э      6a  j      e8  è     438  и      63  c      69  i
   74  t      6d  m      61  a     43f  п      76  v      72  r
   6e  n     43b  л    c2a4  스     78  x      e9  é      69  i
   72  r      6f  o     434  д      61  a      66  f      75  u
   6e  n      72  r     448  ш      6e  n      61  a      66  f
   67  g     440  р      2d  -      6f  o      6d  m      74  t
   6a  j      67  g      6e  n      65  e      72  r      76  v
  447  ч      69  i     56f  կ      63  c      74  t      64  d
  432  в      65  e      65  e      79  y      61  a      69  i
   69  i      6e  n      72  r      61  a      61  a      6f  o
   6e  n    10d4  ე      74  t    b2e4  다     6e  n      61  a
   67  g    10e3  უ      68  h      75  u      72  r      65  e
   62  b      67  g      61  a      73  s      75  u      6e  n
   75  u      64  d      6b  k      65  e      73  s
   6f  o      67  g     119  ę      6e  n      61  a    (all Latin
   61  a      65  e      6d  m      6d  m      65  e     lowercase)
   77  w      67  g      64  d      e7  ç      6e  n
  43c  м      68  h      76  v     3bd  ν      73  s
   e1  á      eb  ë      61  a    10dc  ნ      73  s
   fa  ú     441  с      6f  o      74  t      65  e
   63  c      63  c      6e  n      6b  k      71  q
   65  e      65  e      6c  l     441  с      75  u
   61  a     430  а      74  t     442  т      68  h
   fa  ú      61  a      69  i      65  e      63  c
  435  е      74  t      70  p      7a  z      65  e
   61  a      73  s      74  t      7a  z
   72  r      69  i      69  i     43a  к   (all Latin
   69  i    10d1  ბ      64  d      65  e    lowercase,
   6e  n    10d3  დ      74  t      65  e    3 accented)
   6f  o      6e  n      64  d      71  q
  11f  ğ     17e  ž      74  t     281  ʁ
   6a  j      65  e      7a  z      6e  n
   6a  j      72  r      72  r      6d  m
  445  х      eb  ë    bc14  바    173  ų
 b97c  를     64  d    baa8  모     76  v
   6c  l      6a  j     43d  н      72  r
   68  h     456  і     456  і    d558  하
   65  e      73  s      73  s     107  ć
   62  b      64  d      61  a      61  a
   6a  j     447  ч     57d  ս      69  i
  44c  ь      64  d      64  d      69  i
  440  р      6d  m      65  e      6f  o
   65  e      e9  é      6e  n      61  a
   72  r      66  f      6f  o     3af  ί
  3b1  α    10dc  ნ      77  w    10d8  ი
   61  a      7a  z      69  i      fa  ú
   64  d      69  i      67  g     439  й
   75  u      fd  ý      6e  n     440  р
   61  a      65  e      72  r      61  a
   72  r      75  u      68  h      73  s
  44d  э      74  t      69  i      6e  n
 b098  나     eb  ë      73  s     42a  Ъ
   73  s      6e  n      75  u     448  ш
   74  t     43f  п      61  a      6e  n
   68  h      6f  o     117  ė      77  w
   61  a      6f  o      65  e     251  ɑ
   61  a     435  е      6d  m      61  a
  442  т      73  s      e6  æ      6d  m
  442  т      61  a      6d  m      69  i
   e9  é      68  h      65  e      65  e
   61  a    10d8  ი      73  s      61  a
  3c1  ρ    10d0  ა      69  i    c57d  약
   79  y      75  u      72  r      75  u
              64  d      73  s      65  e
                         70  p      64  d
                       d06c  크     72  r
                        435  е      6b  k
                        456  і     3b9  ι
                         61  a     3b5  ε
                         75  u    10e1  ს
                         6b  k      72  r
                        56b  ի     43e  о
                         65  e     435  е
                         6e  n      73  s
                                    67  g
                                    61  a
                                   43d  н
                                   443  у
                                    61  a
                                    68  h
DECIMAL  CODES                                          A6           D7
                        D3        A4       D5           Apache:      Destiny:
D1            A2        Destiny:  Apache:  Destiny:
Destiny:      Apache:                                   Is this      Will this
                        Invalid   Is       Should the   a valid      succesfully
Can Asphalt   What is   connec-   this     operator     instruction  signoff
respond       the bug   tion      code     precedence   sequence     an Orion
to this?      here?     string?   wrong?   be changed?  in Stencil?  connection?

  121  y     328  ň     105  i     111  o     101  e     103  g      1083  л
  117  u     116  t     105  i      98  b     105  i     118  v      1081  й
  100  d     100  d     110  n     106  j     117  u     108  l      1086  о
  100  d     100  d      97  a     111  o     263  ć     101  e      1077  е
   97  a     101  e     109  m     110  n     109  m     103  g      1080  и
 1076  д      98  b     111  o     100  d     101  e     103  g      1090  т
   97  a    1103  я      97  a     112  p     110  n     114  r      1090  т
   97  a     117  u     111  o   50696  예    353  š     108  l      1085  н
  117  u     109  m     117  u     101  e     115  s     115  s      1080  и
  116  t    1072  а     114  r      99  c     114  r      97  a      1103  я
  104  h    1074  в      97  a     103  g     113  q     121  y      1080  и
  114  r     114  r     103  g     107  k     101  e      97  a      1090  т
 1072  а     100  d     105  i     305  ı     117  u     111  o      1080  и
 1089  с      99  c     107  k     945  α     105  i     111  o      1084  м
  118  v    4328  შ     114  r    4312  ი     111  o     109  m      1088  р
  101  e    4328  შ     117  u    4312  ი     114  r     114  r      1077  е
  974  ώ     117  u     103  g     246  ö     105  i     105  i      1087  п
  114  r     110  n      97  a    1082  к     104  h     117  u      1078  ж
  110  n     101  e     114  r    1074  в     108  l      99  c
  108  l     121  y     105  i     107  k     105  i     101  e    (all Cyrillic
  107  k     110  n     122  z     105  i     106  j     103  g      lowercase)
   97  a     101  e     111  o     119  w     115  s     116  t
 1101  э     106  j     232  è    1080  и      99  c     105  i
  116  t     109  m      97  a    1087  п     118  v     114  r
  110  n    1083  л   49828  스    120  x     233  é     105  i
  114  r     111  o    1076  д      97  a     102  f     117  u
  110  n     114  r    1096  ш     110  n      97  a     102  f
  103  g    1088  р      45  -     111  o     109  m     116  t
  106  j     103  g     110  n     101  e     114  r     118  v
 1095  ч     105  i    1391  կ      99  c     116  t     100  d
 1074  в     101  e     101  e     121  y      97  a     105  i
  105  i     110  n     114  r      97  a      97  a     111  o
  110  n    4308  ე     116  t   45796  다    110  n      97  a
  103  g    4323  უ     104  h     117  u     114  r     101  e
   98  b     103  g      97  a     115  s     117  u     110  n
  117  u     100  d     107  k     101  e     115  s
  111  o     103  g     281  ę     110  n      97  a    (all Latin
   97  a     101  e     109  m     109  m     101  e     lowercase)
  119  w     103  g     100  d     231  ç     110  n
 1084  м     104  h     118  v     957  ν     115  s
  225  á     235  ë      97  a    4316  ნ     115  s
  250  ú    1089  с     111  o     116  t     101  e
   99  c      99  c     110  n     107  k     113  q
  101  e     101  e     108  l    1089  с     117  u
   97  a    1072  а     116  t    1090  т     104  h
  250  ú      97  a     105  i     101  e      99  c
 1077  е     116  t     112  p     122  z     101  e
   97  a     115  s     116  t     122  z
  114  r     105  i     105  i    1082  к   (all Latin
  105  i    4305  ბ     100  d     101  e    lowercase,
  110  n    4307  დ     116  t     101  e    3 accented)
  111  o     110  n     100  d     113  q
  287  ğ     382  ž     116  t     641  ʁ
  106  j     101  e     122  z     110  n
  106  j     114  r     114  r     109  m
 1093  х     235  ë   48148  바    371  ų
47484  를    100  d   47784  모    118  v
  108  l     106  j    1085  н     114  r
  104  h    1110  і    1110  і   54616  하
  101  e     115  s     115  s     263  ć
   98  b     100  d      97  a      97  a
  106  j    1095  ч    1405  ս     105  i
 1100  ь     100  d     100  d     105  i
 1088  р     109  m     101  e     111  o
  101  e     233  é     110  n      97  a
  114  r     102  f     111  o     943  ί
  945  α    4316  ნ     119  w    4312  ი
   97  a     122  z     105  i     250  ú
  100  d     105  i     103  g    1081  й
  117  u     253  ý     110  n    1088  р
   97  a     101  e     114  r      97  a
  114  r     117  u     104  h     115  s
 1101  э     116  t     105  i     110  n
45208  나    235  ë     115  s    1066  Ъ
  115  s     110  n     117  u    1096  ш
  116  t    1087  п      97  a     110  n
  104  h     111  o     279  ė     119  w
   97  a     111  o     101  e     593  ɑ
   97  a    1077  е     109  m      97  a
 1090  т     115  s     230  æ     109  m
 1090  т      97  a     109  m     105  i
  233  é     104  h     101  e     101  e
   97  a    4312  ი     115  s      97  a
  961  ρ    4304  ა     105  i   50557  약
  121  y     117  u     114  r     117  u
             100  d     115  s     101  e
                        112  p     100  d
                      53356  크    114  r
                       1077  е     107  k
                       1110  і     953  ι
                         97  a     949  ε
                        117  u    4321  ს
                        107  k     114  r
                       1387  ի    1086  о
                        101  e    1077  е
                        110  n     115  s
                                   103  g
                                    97  a
                                  1085  н
                                  1091  у
                                    97  a
                                   104  h
```

[[Online UTF-8 table]](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

```
decimal  hex   D1.A2...lines...A6.D7   letter
------- -----  ---------------------   ------------------------------------

punctuation (just one)
    45    2d          D3               -

Latin lowercase (a = 97/61)
    97    61    D1                     aaaaaaaaaaaa
    97    61       A2                              aa
    97    61          D3                             aaaaaaaaaa
    97    61             A4                                    aaaaaaaaa
    97    61                D5                                          aaaa
    97    61                   A6                                           aaa
    98    62    D1                     bb
    98    62       A2                    b
    98    62             A4               b
    99    63    D1                     c
    99    63       A2                   cc
    99    63             A4               cc
    99    63                D5              cc
    99    63                   A6             c
   100    64    D1                     ddd
   100    64       A2                     dddddddd
   100    64             A4                       dd
   100    64          D3                            dddd
   100    64                   A6                       d
   101    65    D1                     eeee
   101    65       A2                      eeeeeeee
   101    65          D3                           eeeee
   101    65             A4                             eeeeeeee
   101    65                D5                                  eeeeee
   101    65                   A6                                     eee
   102    66       A2                  f
   102    66                D5          f
   102    66                   A6        f
   103    67    D1                     gg
   103    67       A2                    gggg
   103    67          D3                     ggg
   103    67             A4                     gg
   103    67                   A6                 gggg
   104    68    D1                     hhh
   104    68       A2                     hh
   104    68          D3                    hh
   104    68             A4                   h
   104    68                D5                 hh
   105    69    D1                     ii
   105    69       A2                    iii
   105    69          D3                    iiiiiiiii
   105    69             A4                          iiii
   105    69                D5                           iiii
   105    69                   A6                            iiii
   106    6a    D1                     jjjj
   106    6a       A2                      jj
   106    6a             A4                  j
   106    6a                D5                j
   107    6b    D1                     k
   107    6b          D3                kkk
   107    6b             A4                kkkk
   108    6c    D1                     ll
   108    6c          D3                 l
   108    6c                D5            l
   108    6c                   A6          ll
   109    6d       A2                  mmm
   109    6d          D3                  mmmm
   109    6d             A4                   mmm
   109    6d                D5                   mm
   109    6d                   A6                  m
   110    6e    D1                     nnnnn
   110    6e       A2                       nnnnn
   110    6e          D3                         nnnnnn
   110    6e             A4                            nnnnnn
   110    6e                D5                               nnn
   110    6e                   A6                               n
   111    6f    D1                     oo
   111    6f       A2                    ooo
   111    6f          D3                    ooooo
   111    6f             A4                      oooo
   111    6f                D5                       o
   111    6f                   A6                     ooo
   112    70          D3               pp
   112    70             A4              p
   113    71             A4            q
   113    71                D5          qq
   114    72    D1                     rrrrrr
   114    72       A2                        rrr
   114    72          D3                        rrrrrrr
   114    72             A4                            rrr
   114    72                D5                            rrrr
   114    72                   A6                             rrr
   115    73    D1                     s
   115    73       A2                   sss
   115    73          D3                   ssss
   115    73             A4                    sss
   115    73                D5                    sssss
   115    73                   A6                      s
   116    74    D1                     ttt
   116    74       A2                     ttt
   116    74          D3                     ttttt
   116    74             A4                       t
   116    74                D5                     t
   116    74                   A6                   tt
   117    75    D1                     uuuu
   117    75       A2                      uuuu
   117    75          D3                       uuuu
   117    75             A4                        uu
   117    75                D5                       uuuu
   117    75                   A6                        uu
   118    76    D1                     v
   118    76          D3                v
   118    76             A4              v
   118    76                D5            v
   118    76                   A6          vv
   119    77    D1                     w
   119    77          D3                w
   119    77             A4              ww
   120    78             A4            x
   121    79    D1                     yy
   121    79       A2                    y
   121    79             A4               y
   121    79                   A6          y
   122    7a       A2                  z
   122    7a          D3                zz
   122    7a             A4               zz

Latin lowercase miscellany (begins at à = 224/e0)
   225    e1    D1                     á
   230    e6          D3               æ
   231    e7             A4            ç
   232    e8          D3               è
   233    e9    D1                     é
   233    e9       A2                   é
   233    e9                D5           é
   235    eb       A2                  ëëë
   246    f6             A4            ö
   250    fa    D1                     úú
   250    fa             A4              ú
   253    fd       A2                  ý
   263   107             A4            ć
   263   107                D5          ć
   279   117          D3               ė
   281   119          D3               ę
   287   11f    D1                     ğ
   305   131             A4            ı
   328   148       A2                  ň
   353   161                D5         š
   371   173             A4            ų
   382   17e       A2                  ž

IPA extensions (begins at ɐ = 592/250)
   593   251             A4            ɑ
   641   281             A4            ʁ

Greek lowercase (α = 945/3b1  -  ω = 969/3c9)
   943   3af             A4            ί
   945   3b1    D1                     α
   945   3b1             A4             α
   949   3b5             A4            ε
   953   3b9             A4            ι
   957   3bd             A4            ν
   961   3c1    D1                     ρ
   974   3ce    D1                     ώ

Cyrillic, all but Ъ lowercase (А = 1040/410, а = 1072/430)
  1066   42a             A4            Ъ
  1072   430    D1                     а
  1072   430       A2                   аа
  1074   432    D1                     в
  1074   432       A2                   в
  1074   432             A4              в
  1076   434    D1                     д
  1076   434          D3                д
  1077   435    D1                     е
  1077   435       A2                   е
  1077   435          D3                 е
  1077   435             A4               е
  1077   435                     D7        ее
  1078   436                     D7    ж
  1080   438             A4            и
  1080   438                     D7     ииии
  1081   439             A4            й
  1081   439                     D7     й
  1082   43a             A4            кк
  1083   43b       A2                  л
  1083   43b                     D7     л
  1084   43c    D1                     м
  1084   43c                     D7     м
  1085   43d          D3               н
  1085   43d             A4             н
  1085   43d                     D7      н
  1086   43e             A4            о
  1086   43e                     D7     о
  1087   43f       A2                  п
  1087   43f             A4             п
  1087   43f                     D7      п
  1088   440    D1                     р
  1088   440       A2                   р
  1088   440             A4              р
  1088   440                     D7       р
  1089   441    D1                     с
  1089   441       A2                   с
  1089   441             A4              с
  1090   442    D1                     тт
  1090   442             A4              т
  1090   442                     D7       ттт
  1091   443             A4            у
  1093   445    D1                     х
  1095   447    D1                     ч
  1095   447       A2                   ч
  1096   448          D3               ш
  1096   448             A4             ш
  1100   44c    D1                     ь
  1101   44d    D1                     ээ
  1103   44f       A2                  я
  1103   44f                     D7     я
  1110   456       A2                  і
  1110   456          D3                іі

Armenian lowercase (ա = 1377/561)
  1387   56b          D3               ի
  1391   56f          D3               կ
  1405   57d          D3               ս

Georgian (ა = 4034/10d0)
  4304  10d0       A2                  ა
  4305  10d1       A2                  ბ
  4307  10d3       A2                  დ
  4308  10d4       A2                  ე
  4312  10d8       A2                  ი
  4312  10d8             A4             იიი
  4316  10dc       A2                  ნ
  4316  10dc             A4             ნ
  4321  10e1             A4            ს
  4323  10e3       A2                  უ
  4328  10e8       A2                  შშ

Hangul (begins at 가 = 44032/ac00)
 45208  b098    D1                     나
 45796  b2e4             A4            다
 47484  b97c    D1                     를
 47784  baa8          D3               모
 48148  bc14          D3               바
 49828  c2a4          D3               스
 50557  c57d             A4            약
 50696  c608             A4            예
 53356  d06c          D3               크
 54616  d558             A4            하
```

```
D1 Destiny: Can Asphalt respond to this?
   yuddaдaauthrасveώrnlkaэtnrngjчвingbuoawмáúceaúеarinoğjjх를lhebjьрerαaduarэ나sthaaттéaρy

A2 Apache: What is the bug here?
   ňtddebяumавrdcშშuneynejmлorрgienეუgdgeghëсceаatsiბდnžerëdjіsdчdméfნziýeutënпooеsahიაud

D3 Destiny: Invalid connection string?
   iinamoaouragikrugarizoèa스дш-nկerthakęmdvaonltiptidtdtzr바모ніsaսdenowignrhisuaėemæmesirsp크еіaukիen

A4 Apache: Is this code wrong?
   objondp예ecgkıαიიöквkiwипxanoecya다usenmçνნtkстezzкeeqʁnmųvr하ćaiioaίიúйрasnЪшnwɑamiea약uedrkιεსrоеsgaнуah

D5 Destiny: Should the operator precedence be changed?
   (all lowercase Latin, 3 accented)
   eiućmenšsrqeuiorihlijscvéfamrtaanrusaenssequhce
      ć   š                é

A6 Apache: Is this a valid instruction sequence in Stencil?
   (all lowercase Latin)
   gvleggrlsayaoomriucegtiriuftvdioaen

D7 Destiny: Will this succesfully signoff an Orion connection?
   (all lowercase Cyrillic)
   лйоеиттнияитимрепж
```